# How to create a method that will insert data into sql using c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

i want a method that will insert data into sql. For example i have a class `

```
public partial class Users : Form
{
    public Users()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      connections.con.Close();
      connections.con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into login_tbl values('" + loginName.Text + "','" + loginpass.Text + "')", connections.con);
     `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

but i want a method that will send the query and values by its parameters such as

```
model.dbcontext db = new model.dbcontext();
db.Insert(sql, param);
```

what will i do in user class and dbcontext class to sort out this problem??
**here's dbcontext class**

```
 class dbcontext
{` public void Insert(string sql,datatype??? param)
    {
        connections.con.Close();
        connections.con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connections.con))
        {

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }`}
```

Thnx in advance.

Comment: "Please, please, I do not want to even try reading documentation, do my work for me". Do I translate this right? Sorry, - 1 and voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend if you are already working EF, map that table as an entity and add a new row using `DbSet<TEntity>.Add` method.

The method you are looking is [`ExecuteSqlCommnad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx), which is useful to send non-query commands to the database like an insert.

```
public void Insert(string sql,params object[] parameters)
{
   Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,parameters);
}
```